# Поиск наиболее подходящих записей в базе данных MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Привет! У меня есть база данных MySQL и в ней таблица с 2-я полями, поля типа int. Не может быть несколько записей с одинаковым первым и вторым полем. У меня есть массив чисел m. Мне надо получить значение первого поля, у которого во втором поле значения больше соответствует числам из массива, как-то так.

То бишь у меня есть таблица:

```
param1  param2
1       111
2       111
2       222
2       444
3       222
3       555
```

И массив:

```
111 222 333
```

Мне надо получить из таблицы число 2. Буду очень признателен за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select param1, count(param1) as x from tbl
where param2 in (111, 222, 333)
group by param1
order by x desc
limit 1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3cdae5/2

Comment: Спасибо большое, узнал много нового. :)

Answer (score 1):

Через два запроса: выбирай первое значение только с одним условием, записывай значение, а потом выбирай с двумя.